# Extending Fiber to add an operation

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fibers

I have some concurrent `Service` which I want to control an execution of. Precisely I want to be able use all operations `Fiber` provides as well as some other business-specific things. I'm currently considering to just inherit it from `Fiber`. Here it is:

```
trait Svc[F[_]] extends Fiber[F, Unit]{

    def usefulOp: F[Unit]

}
```

By using such an approach I added `Fiber`'s operations `join` and `cancel` to the service as well as use something that is related to business logic. The problem I see is that if the `Svc` is cancelled and `usefulOp` is called on it there might be a problem.

What would be a solution to workaround the issue? Probably to prohibit calling `usefulOp` on a cancelled `Svc` somehow?

Comment: I do not believe you should extend Fiber _(it even surprises me that it is not final)_. Your business logic should use a Fiber, not being one.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, I also thought that extending `Fiber` is kind of strange